# Lubridate::round_date() does not accept date

Tags: r, date, rounding, lubridate

I'm learning the R package lubridate. I discovered that the `round_date()` function does not provide the correct answer when the input is a date. The input must be a datetime. `floor_date()` and `ceiling_date()` have no such problem.

For example,

```r
date1 <- as_datetime("2022-09-23")
date2 <- as_datetime("2022-05-19")
round_date(date1, "year")
#> [1] "2023-01-01 UTC"
round_date(date2, "year")
#> [1] "2022-01-01 UTC"

date3 <- as_date("2022-09-23")
date4 <- as_date("2022-05-19")
round_date(date3, "year")
#> [1] "2022-01-01"
round_date(date4, "year")
#> [1] "2022-01-01"
```

| Input string | Conversion | Output class | round_date() |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "2022-09-23" | as_datetime | "POSIXct" "POSIXt" | 2023-01-01 UTC |
| "" | as_date | "Date" | 2022-01-01 |
| "2022-05-19" | as_datetime | "POSIXct" "POSIXt" | 2022-01-01 UTC |
| "" | as_date | "Date" | 2022-01-01 |

Is this behavior a "feature" or a defect?